# install Ion cube on local server

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, ioncube

I want to use a WordPress site on local server by XAMPP but it has encoded with ion cube, when I run the web this error will occur:

`Script error: the ionCube Loader for PHP needs to be installed. The ionCube Loader is the industry standard PHP extension for running protected PHP code, and can usually be added easily to a PHP installation. For Loaders please visit get-loader.ioncube.com and for an instructional video please see http://ioncu.be/LV`

I found that should run the `http://localhost/loader-wizard.php` I have the error in the picture.[image: error]

what should I do?

I downloaded the following archive of Windows VC16 x86-64 Loaders:
`https://downloads.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_win_vc16_x86-64.zip`
and put the Loader files in `\xampp\php\ext`.
Edit the file G:\xampp\php\php.ini and before any other zend_extension lines ensure that the following is included:
`zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\ioncube_loader_win_8.1.dll"`
and restart the Apache server software several times